# Create custom nav_menu for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu, nav

I m trying to create custom nav_menu for wordpress but I don't know to do. I want menu item in this template:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
<li class="">
    <a href="index.html">
        <i class="menu-icon fa fa-tachometer"></i>
        <span class="menu-text"> Dashboard </span>
    </a>

    <b class="arrow"></b>
</li>

<li class="">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
        <i class="menu-icon fa fa-desktop"></i>
        <span class="menu-text"> UI &amp; Elements </span>

        <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-down"></b>
    </a>

    <b class="arrow"></b>

    <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>

                Layouts
                <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-down"></b>
            </a>

            <b class="arrow"></b>

            <ul class="submenu">
                <li class="">
                    <a href="top-menu.html">
                        <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                        Top Menu
                    </a>

                    <b class="arrow"></b>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I search in internet and find a library as **Walker_Nav_Menu** but I don't understand to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it using walker class. see following code:

```
class custom_Menu_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    var $number = 1;

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

        $atts = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
        $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
        $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';

        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args );

        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .='<i class="menu-icon fa fa-tachometer"></i><span class="menu-text">';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .='</span>';
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }

}
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        "container"         => "nav",
        "container_class"   => "container",
        "container_id"      => "nav",
        "fallback_cb"       => false,
        "menu_class"        => "six columns omega main-nav sf-menu",
        "theme_location"    => "primary",
        "walker"            => new custom_Menu_Walker(),
    )
);
```

Here, Apply condition as you required

Comment: Thanks for helping. Can you customize your code for my html. unfortunately I don't understand. Thanks